# I need to update an existing URL

Tags: url, link

[image]I have inherited a Craft website and need to update an existing URL, it will open a PDF document, so I need to replace an updated PDF

I have very basic Craft knowledge so need assistance.  I have added a Screenshot below showing the inforamtion behind the link which I hope helps

Comment: We need much more information in order to help you. How is the link generated, is it a plugin route or is it the cp asset url? Maybe you could provide us the template where the link is generated so we can assume where it comes from. Otherwise there a plenty of ways how the creator did it

Comment: Your template, not your html. But it seems like it's a hard coded link to a specific file. So you might have to rename the file or create a custom route

Answer (score 2):

You can replace a file directly in the control panel. Navigate to Assets, select the file you want to replace and then click the cog icon to select the “Replace file” action.

[image]

Comment: But this only works if the creator used that method. If the creator of the site just included a hard link to the file or passed a generated link from a plugin it won't work

Comment: Right, the answer might be wrong. I simply assumed it’s an asset element because of the file path /uploads/files/… @RobinSchambach

Comment: I did so too, but I thought craft always adds the site url in the `getUrl` function but maybe I'm wrong and there is a config variable to remove/change that behavior

Comment: It only does so when `siteUrl` is setup and set to a fully qualified URL.